# Django filter multiple value in the same column

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have set up the column where one of the table is called Establishment_Type

Now, I am trying to filter according to Establishment_Type.

Here is my view.py code

```
class ShopDetailAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ShopDetailSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Shop.objects.all()
        type = self.request.query_params.get('type', None)
        type2 = self.request.query_params.get('type2', None)
        if type is not None and type2 is None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(Establishment_Type = type)
        elif type is not None and type2 is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(Q(Establishment_Type = type) | Q(Establishment_Type = type2))
        return queryset
```

In the url, I query by typing:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop/search/?type=Restaurant&type2=Petrol%20Station
```

Which only filter Establishment_Type = Restaurant but not include Establishment_Type = Petrol Station

Here is my `urls.py` within my app called shop:

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', ShopListAPIView.as_view(), name = 'list' ),
    #####
    url(r'^create/$', ShopCreateAPIView.as_view(), name = 'create' ),
    url(r'^search/$', ShopDetailAPIView.as_view(), name = 'detail'),
]
```

Was my url for filtering 2 Establishment type wrong?

Do I need to change something in my code in order to filter 2 values in column Establishment_Type?

Comment: Your URL makes no sense. You haven't even included `type2`.

Comment: forget to add that in when i type. i have added type2 in the url and it doesn't work as well.

Comment: I think you want `queryset.filter(Establishment_Type__in=types)`, where types is list of your not None types.

Comment: BTW instead of `.get('key', None)` use just `.get('key')`. It's the same.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Thyrst' for advising me to use Establishment_Type__in=types

I have modify my code this way for my filter to work

```
class ShopDetailAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ShopDetailSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Shop.objects.all()
        type = self.request.query_params.get('type', None)
        type = type.split(',')
        if type is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(Establishment_Type__in = type)
        return queryset
```

so type is now list, therefore when entered the url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop/search/?type=Restaurant,Petrol%20Station
```

it filters according to Restaurant and Petrol Station.

it also works when entering just 1 value or more.

This is good for now but I feel like there might be a better way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

There is an even simpler way to achieve this using the [`django-filter` package](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). Deep within the [`django-filter` documentation](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filterset.html#declaring-filterable-fields), it mentions that you can use "a dictionary of field names mapped to a list of lookups".

Your code would be updated like so:

```
# views.py

from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class ShopDetailAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Shop.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ShopDetailSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = {
        'type': ["in", "exact"]
    }
```

Now in the URL you would add `__in` to the filter before supplying your list of parameters and it would work as you expect:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop/search/?type__in=Restaurant,Petrol%20Station
```

The `django-filter` documentation on what lookup filters are available is quite poor, but the `in` lookup filter is mentioned in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#in) itself.